# New motherboard not outputting right audio channel to splitter

Tags: audio, motherboard, splitter, amplification

Just finished setting up my OS' after upgrading RAM, motherboard and CPU and quickly discovered that audio wasn't outputting correctly. I currently use a HD650 paired with a Schitt Asgard 2 which in turn is connected to the motherboard's green audio output with a splitter. This worked perfectly fine with the previous config but now, not so much.

I've tried plugging the amplifier up to my phone and there it works without any problems, so the cable is good. I've also plugged my Apple Earpods into the audio output I'm trying to use, and yet again, it works. Both left and right channel is present. I've also tried this in both Windows 10 and Arch Linux with the same results, no right audio channel when using the splitter.

I upgraded from an i5 4670k to the i5 6600k. Motherboard went from MSI Z97 MPower to MSI Z170A Krait Gaming.

Comment: Try another stereo audio device.  The other devices you tried are single audio channel devices.

Comment: A different headset? I just tried my old Beyerdynamic DT770 Pro and this works as well when plugged directly into the back of the computer.

Comment: do you mean a "Y Cable" or a 1/8-inch-stereo male to (2) rca mono (L/R) male cable? If it is a Y cable, is it "stereo to 2x stereo" or is it "stereo to 2x mono"?

Comment: Note that  you can easily test the voltage at the male ends using a voltmeter: I *think* headphone out should be +/- 1 volt DC

Comment: It's a 3.5 mm stereo plug to 2 x RCA male. I'd love to test it using a voltmeter but I lack one unfortunately.